# Android create transparent layer with gradient

Tags: android, transparency, linear-gradients

I want to create a trasparent overlay to create a drop shadow on titlebar.

I create a custom view and in costructor

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{
            Color.TRANSPARENT,
            Color.BLACK,
            Color.BLACK });
        drawable.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
//        drawable.setAlpha(255);
        this.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

The view doesn't appear on the screen. If i remove Color.TRANSPARENT the view appear but i need gradient must have 50% alpha.

Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can set alpha using color code here

Answer (score 1):

try with this colors

```
int colors[] = { 0x00000000 , 0x40000000, 0x80000000 };
```

Just use an 8-digit color value ARGB